# How to configure PyDev to use 32-bit Python Interpreter In Eclipse, on OSX Lion

Tags: python, eclipse, osx-lion, 32bit-64bit, pydev

I am running OSX Lion and have installed python2.7 from python.org (this distribution can run in both 64bit and 32bit mode). I have also installed the wxPython package. I can run python scripts that import wxPython from the Terminal by explicitly using the **32-bit** version. I would like to run the same scripts in Eclipse, but cannot. I configure PyDev to use python.org's interpreter, but it defaults to 64-bit (I check this by printing sys.maxint). I cannot figure out how to make PyDev use the 32-bit interpreter.
I have tried configuring the PyDev python interpreter to point to:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-32

but it ends up using:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

How can I configure PyDev to use the 32-bit python interpreter in Eclipse on OSX Lion?

I appreciate any input regarding this matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpreter used in PyDev is computed from sys.executable...

Now, a doubt: if you start a shell with /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-32 and do 'print sys.executable', which executable appears?

Now, onto a workaround... you can try replacing the places where sys.executable appears in plugins/org.python.pydev/PySrc/interpreterInfo.py to point to  '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-32'

That's the script where it decides which interpreter to actually use... (still, it's strange that sys.executable would point to a different location...)

Comment: Modifying the script named interpreterInfo.py as described, worked. Thank you.