# Eclipse running 64-bit Python, rather than 32-bit

Tags: python, eclipse, osx-lion, 32bit-64bit, pydev

I am running OS X Lion, Python 2.7, and I am trying to setup Pygame to work with PyDev in Eclipse. I set up PyDev to use a custom-installed Python (not the default one). I forced this install to use 32-bit, which works fine in the Terminal - I can import Pygame, and other modules. However, when I use it in PyDev, it gives me a `no matching architecture` error. It also appears to be running in 64-bit mode.

The paths to the interpreter are the same.

```
import sys
print ("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)
```

prints out `('7fffffff', False)` while using Terminal, but in Eclipse/PyDev it prints out `('7fffffffffffffff', True)`

The two paths (using sys.executable) are:
In Terminal it is:
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`

And in Eclipse it is
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`

The path to the interpreter I used is: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`
I also tried manually specifying the interpreter in Terminal - Using the above path. It worked.

The default python that comes with the system is  `/usr/bin/python`

I am using a 32-bit version of Eclipse classic as shown by an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305076/how-to-set-up-pygame-with-eclipse).

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Are you absolutely *certain* the paths to the interpreter ar the same?

Comment: I second this question, it's really unusual that the paths to the interpreter are the same

Comment: I added the paths to the Question.

Comment: thanks, what is the path to the default python (x64) installation?

Comment: I am pretty sure that system python is located in `usr/bin/python`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a method describe in an answer to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237508/how-to-configure-pydev-to-use-32-bit-python-interpreter-in-eclipse-on-osx-lion).

The answer said to go to your plugins/org.python.pydev/pysrc and open interpreterInfo.py. Then you replace all the instances of `sys.executable` with the path to the interpreter you want.
In my case, this meant changing them to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Version/2.7/bin/python2.7`

After that, open up eclipse and create a new interpreter with the same path, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instruct eclipse to use 32-bit python.

Right-click on your project -> properties -> PyDen/Interpreter grammar and select "Click here to configure an interpreter not listed"

After you add your new python binary (e.g. C:\Python27\python.exe), you go back to the interpreter menu in the properties window and you select this interpreter from the corresponding drop-down menu.

Comment: I have setup Eclipse to use the 32-bit interpreter, and when I use that same interpreter in the Terminal it works fine, something in Eclipse is resetting it to 64 bit somehow.

Comment: can you please write the full paths of your two interpreters including the binary name? E.g. C:/python/python.exe and C:/python64/python.exe